# ruby... pull based web framework & design patterns

Tags: ruby, design-patterns, architecture, soa

Please excuse the verbosity here but I need to be detailed.

I recently built a framework that uses a somewhat unconventional pattern. Essentially it's pull based from the view. Rails, imo, is a push based pattern. You push data from the model through the controller onto the view.

In my design the view requests data using custom Liquid (liquidmarkup.org) tags & drops. That triggers calls to backend API's  (or return from memcache) which returns JSON which gets converted into ruby Arrays and Hashes which Liquid can iterate through and use as objects within the view. No business logic in the view. It's purely pull.

When the user posts something, a handler (aka controller, but only for PUTS & POSTS) deals with validation & passing along data again to the back-end services. Depending on the outcome the user can be redirected, rendered a page, etc...

The major advantage to this approach is that our frontend guys can design without us stepping on each others toes and also fits in nicely with our SOA environment.

My question... What, if any, design pattern does this resemble or is it a combination? Does anybody know of comparable frameworks using a similar approach? I'd really like to get ideas on improving this architecture and maybe even one day build an open source version. It's worked brilliantly for us so far.

I look forward to your comments.

Comment: Even if it's not ruby, your description makes me think of AngularJS (http://angularjs.org). Maybe you could take a look?